# jqGrid delete Row while in edit mode and pass additional data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i'm having an issue passing additional delete data when row is in edit mode (inlinde editing) and the user click on delete(navgrid).

here is my code:

```
    .navGrid('#' + childGridPagerID, {add: false,edit: true,del: true,   cancel: true, refresh: true, view: true, search:false},{},
                {// edit options
                        editCaption: "Exercise Special Note",template: template,
                        errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                            return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
                        },
                },
                { // del options
                    mtype:"POST", reloadAfterSubmit:true, serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                        var selRowId = $("#" + childGridID).jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        //console.log(selRowID);

                        if ($("#"+selRowId).attr("editable") === "1") {
                            $("#" + childGridID).editRow(selRowId, false);
                            var rowdata = $("#" + childGridID).getRowData(selRowId);
                        }
                        console.log(rowdata);

                    // append postdata with any information
                    }
                }
    )
```

i know the documentation says that getRowData will not work while in edit mode so i tried to disabled the edit mode right before i call the getRowData but is still get the html in the console log instead of the real data. i also saw that i could save the row first and then get my data before deleting it, the issue is most of the fields are required and the user might delete the row without filling all the field which would prompt the user to enter the required field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem the you should call `restoreRow` or `saveRow` instead of the usage `editRow` inside of `serializeDelData`. By the way the `postdata` contains the id of deleting row, thus you don't need to use `.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow')` to get the same information. The modified code could be:

```
serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
    var rowId = postdata.id; // or postdata[this.p.prmNames[id]]

    if ($("#"+rowId).attr("editable") === "1") {
        $(this).restoreRow(rowId);
        var rowdata = $(this).getRowData(selRowId);
        console.log(rowdata);
    }

    // append postdata with any information
    ...

    return postdata;
}
```

By the way you can consider to use another callback to extend the information, posted to the server. For example the goal of `onclickSubmit` is exactly providing such information. It can return `{}` or an object which will be merged with the main information. The code could be something like

```
onclickSubmit: function (deleteOptions, rowids) {
    $(this).jqGrid("restoreRow", rowids);
    var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", postdata);
    return {id1: rowData.id1, id2: rowData.id2};
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg, however i have to mention that this is part of a three level subgrid and when i use var rowID = postdata.id i do not get the real id that allows me to get the rowData. when using this method it returns the index of the row (1, 2, 3,... ) and so on but when i use the getGridParam method i get the real id, in my case it return progGrid_1_table_d_1_1 after which i can retrieve the rowData. Thanks for the help, you are the ultimate master.

Comment: @boulepick: You are welcome! If you have the column which have real id, then you can `key: true` in the column. It informs jqGrid to use the value as the rowid and `postdata.id` will be already what you required. In the case you will be remove the part of your code.